# References for wearable e-health systems for biosignal based health monitoring

Tags: reference-request

Ubiquitous computing refers to ["information technology and computer power, which in principle pervade all everyday objects"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313043303/http://mva.me/educational/hci/read/ubiquitous_computing.pdf) (see Friedewald and Raabe, 2010). A similar form is wearable computing, where the computing device is placed on a persons cloth/body. This topic currently gets much attention: smart watches (e.g., Apple) or glasses (e.g., google glass).

I'm interested in the topic of wearable e-health systems. As I'm just getting started with my research in this area, I'd like to ask for recommendations for good review papers, journals etc. to be used as a starting point.

The European Union has a special policy for eHealth, including various initiatives. Wearable systems [[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313043303/http://mva.me/educational/hci/read/ubiquitous_computing.pdf)] allow for light-weighted, cost-effective, 24h patient monitoring - especially for elderly people - that does not interfere with everyday life.

I am specifically interested in the display and monitoring of clinical relevant biosignals, for instance heart activity measured by ECG, oxygen staturation measured by puls oxygen meters. I am not intersted in patient records, health information systems, patient medication monitoring, privacy, security, compliance, etc., which are also part of eHealth.

A quick search revealed the following references.

**Review papers:**

Chan, Marie, et al. ["Smart wearable systems: Current status and future challenges."](http://ft.parsons.edu/skin/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1-s2.0-S0933365712001182-main.pdf) Artificial intelligence in medicine 56.3 (2012): 137-156.

Mosa, Abu Saleh M., Illhoi Yoo, and Lincoln Sheets. ["A systematic review of healthcare applications for smartphones."](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?hl=en&q=A%20Systematic%20Review%20of%20Healthcare%20Applications%20for%20Smartphones&btnG=&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=) BMC medical informatics and decision making 12.1 (2012): 67.

**Wearable eHealth devices:**

Chung, Wan-Young, Young-Dong Lee, and Sang-Joong Jung. ["A wireless sensor network compatible wearable u-healthcare monitoring system using integrated ECG, accelerometer and SpO 2."](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4649460) Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society, 2008. EMBS 2008. 30th Annual International Conference of the IEEE. IEEE, 2008.

[Watanabe, Hyuma, et al. "Wearable ECG Monitoring and Alerting System Associated with Smartphone: iHeart."](https://www.igi-global.com/article/wearable-ecg-monitoring-and-alerting-system-associated-with-smartphone/107051) International Journal of E-Health and Medical Communications (IJEHMC) 4.4 (2013): 1-15.

Further topics:  there are more specific topic like papers on sensors, security & privacy, protocols & wireless networks, signal analysis & diagnosis from biomedical signals, etc.

Pantelopoulos, Alexandros, and Nikolaos G. Bourbakis. ["A survey on wearable sensor-based systems for health monitoring and prognosis."](https://www.scribd.com/doc/150121466/A-Survey-on-Wearable-Sensor-Based-Systems-for-Health-Monitoring-and-Prognosis) Systems, Man, and Cybernetics, Part C: Applications and Reviews, IEEE Transactions on 40.1 (2010): 1-12.

**Q:**
What are your recommendations for papers in the area of technical aspects of wearable e-health systems, specifically the monitoring and display of biosignals such as those of the cardiovascular system excluding the aspect of security, privacy or compliance?

Comment: You're probably more of an expert on this topic than anyone else here.

Comment: That, and it also seems too broad a question to me. Furthermore, I struggle to view this topic per se as part of computer science; the titles you give strike me to be more in the vein of product development.

Comment: I am a PhD student and certainly not interested in any product development but in computer science(biomedical signal processing, ai/machine learning, research on user interface design for such applications, computerized diagnosis, etc.). The topic of wearable devices is also clearly in the realm of computer science (www.media.mit.edu/wearables/). As I am interested in review papers, the question is kept broad as I don’t know yet which subtopics are of importance. I ask because I am so new to this field that I don't know yet the relevant search terms, authors and journals to look for.

Comment: The topic should fit here, as this site should include more applied computer science, as theoretical computer science already has its own SE site. If only theoretical and not more applied questions are suited for this site, if only stuff like complexity theory fits, then this site would be better merged with cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I am certainly not an expert in this new field I am trying yet to get a glimpse of it and I am only an PhD reseacher. I dont't have any postdoc or professor I can ask in person, therefore the question.

Comment: I edited the question and hope I made the question more specific. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Please don't close this question! I tried my very best to make the question more specific and clear. To my opinion this questiong clearly fits into computer science and into the real of a reference request.

Comment: For the record, while I think no one will be able to answer this question, I don't think that's a reason to close it.

Comment: The reason this is closed is because it is too broad: it asks for recommendations for a list of papers in an entire area.  That's too broad, is changing rapidly, and not suitable for this site's format.  This site is for technical questions that admit a single answer; asking for a big list of papers is not suitable.  See, e.g., http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487/755.  (Whether anyone can answer it or not was not a factor in my vote to close as too broad.  Similarly, whether this fits into computer science wasn't a factor in my vote.)